# Slim NGINX Rewriting Url to Look Nicer

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, vagrant, slim

I am using slim nginx. The site is live, vagrant homestead.  An example of my url is

> myurl.com/?page=admins <-- ugly

I want to make it look like this

> myurl.com/page/admins <-- user friendly
>
> myurl.com/page/orders
>
> simply just want to remove the ? and replace = with /

I've tried this and many other things but no solution for a while now (I am completely new to this so I am a bit lost)

my etc/nginx/sites-available/myurl.com file so far:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name .myurl.com;
    root "/home/vagrant/code/admin";
    index index.html index.htm index.php api.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php$is_args$args;
    }


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/myurl.com-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
                                                                                                                                 location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }



    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/myurl.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myurl.com.key;
}

server {
    rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /?page=$1 last;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://myurl.com;
    }
}
```

last bit of code is my current attempt (suggested by Robert)
Help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this issue for hours and have researched almost all of the available resources out there!

Comment: Are you using Silm PHP framework? If so, you can refer to [Nginx configuration](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html#nginx-configuration) section of Slim user guide.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your users to interact with the application using https://myurl.com/page/admins the rewrite would look similar to this

```
server {
    rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /?page=$1 last;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://1.2.3.4;
    }
}
```

Take a look at either of the following for more information

- https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html